# how to deploying connected app

Tags: oauth2, appexchange, connected-apps

I am trying to create a Connected App and publish in App Exchange ..for that reason if any user will download the App from App Exchange, the connected app should be installed automatically in user org

Comment: Questions about implementation problems need to include a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and the code or metadata to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to deploy Connected Apps to different orgs. Upon first use, they are automatically installed in an org and can then be configured by administrators. Deploying a Connected App to a different org regenerates the client ID and client secret (so as to avoid ambiguity). Your Connected App should exist only in a single org, typically Production or a designated Developer Edition org.